# jQuery and javascript functions are not working with curl

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl

I'm using `curl` and `php` for loading a page in my website, all contents are coming properly but the `java script` and `jQuery` that i had used in that page is not working. Can any one tell the reason and solution for this?
This is the code I used to call the content to my page

```
$c = curl_init("path/to/page.php");
 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $contents = curl_exec($c);
 if (curl_error($c))
 die(curl_error($c));
 $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($c);
```

Here is the page.php I used

```
<h1>Demo 3 - Cat picture.</h1>
 <p>
  You\'ll see that along with the URL and container content, the title has also been updated.
  Using PJAX you can even give pages custom titles, for example

  <a href="page2.php" data-title="Custom title!">this link</a>
   will open page 2  with the title "Custom title!".
 </p>
 <hr/>
 <h3>A picture of a cat.</h3>
 <img src="img/cat.jpg" alt="Picture of a drunk cat" />
 <p>There really isn\'t a good reason for this...</p>
 <script>
 alert("success");
 </script>
```

This all content is displaying except the alert I gave

main_page.php

```
<?php
$title = 'Page 3 - Cat';
$c = curl_init('path/to/page.php');
 curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $contents = curl_exec($c);
 if (curl_error($c))
 die(curl_error($c));
 $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
 curl_close($c);
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_PJAX'] == 'true'){
 echo $contents;
 echo "<title>{$title}</title>";
}else{
 include 'wrapper.php';
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the executable code ? Any errors in console ?

Comment: Can you post `page.php` content? One to do is to check `.js` files path, and essentially checking the console log

Comment: There is no errors in console, functions are jQuery, even an alert also not working

Comment: page.php is with JS script? If yes, try to $.ajax add 'dataType: "script"'.  Look here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ for more info.

Comment: I don't understand why you're forced to `cURL`, the content is hosted on the same server (I assume). So why do a outgoing call when you can use `include` or other AJAX-based alternatives?

Comment: I'm implementing a music player to my website. I don't want to stop the music while changing the navigation. I searched for this problem and find PJAX as a solution. For this I used curl

Comment: You don't do anything with `$contents` in the PHP and the HTML you've shown doesn't include any of the JS that you say isn't working. You need to provide a [test case](http://sscce.org/) that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Issue is hard to diagnose without seeing the larger picture - in particular the context in which `$c = curl_init("path/to/page.php");` etc. is executed.

Comment: Question Updated please check